# Check if EditText input matches SimpleDateFormat Android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, simpledateformat

I've searched a lot about this but I didn't find a way to check if a text written by the user in an EditText matches a SimpleDateFormat, is there a simple way to do that without using regex ?

Here is my SimpleDateFormat :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

And I want to test if a String respects that format.

Comment: I've mistaken SimpleDateFormat for TextFormat. The one I want to compare with the text written by the user is that : `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do this by parsing my string into a date in a try/catch block. If the string is parsable, it matches the SimpleDateFormat :

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String date = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate)).getText().toString(); // EditText to check
    java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
    // If the string can be parsed in date, it matches the SimpleDateFormat
    // Do whatever you want to do if String matches SimpleDateFormat.
}
catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    // Else if there's an exception, it doesn't
    // Do whatever you want to do if it doesn't.        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `TextWatcher` to listen input changes to your `EditText` and may perform appropriate actions in either of its provided method.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //you may perform your checks here
    }
});
```

Comment: I've already tested TextWatcher but its afterTextChanged method is called after each character change so I used an onFocusChangedListener instead, no problem on that. That's comparing the date (string) written by the user with my SimpleDateFormat that I want to.